# Remote commands execution and file acces in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access, administration

Suppose I have a server application installed in a few Linux and Windows machines. Now I would like to control it remotely. That is, I would like to start and stop the application, update the application configuration files, reads the logs remotely.

It looks to be easy in the Linux worlds. I can use `ssh`, `scp`, and probably `nfs` to execute commands in remote Linux machines and access files there. The problem is that I would like to execute commands and access files in remote Linux and Windows machines *uniformly* from a *Windows* machine.  I need also some scripting capabilities too.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use cygwin http://www.cygwin.com/  on your windows machines and install a ssh server with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need graphical tools, use VNC
2. there is an OpenSS implementation targeting Windows at http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/download/
3. since there is (besides Cygwin/MinGW) no possibility to run bash code (ksh/csh/tcsh code as well) you should make yourself familiar with the windows scripting host.